# Problem with web-scraped text using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, visual-studio-2022

I have issues getting text for the first printed item as nothing shows up except a blank line, but there are no issues with the second item text showing up in print. I would like to know if there is a workaround for this text print issue or if there is something about python coding that I have overlooked.

This code has been applied through Visual Studio 2022 using MS Edge web browser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/atp-singles/tokyo/mcdonald-mackenzie-uchida-kaichi/UivPCtWD/")
webpage = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

print(soup.select('li p')[0].text)

print(soup.select('li p')[1].text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get the date? Because if so, the code:

```
print(soup.select('li p')[1].text)
```

For me, I got the date with this line of code:

```
# We want to find the p element with this class
date = soup.find("p", {"class": "list-details__item__date"})["data-dt"]  
print(date)
```

EDIT:
it also worked with your code, you just have to get the *data-dt* attribute

```
print(soup.select('li p')[0]["data-dt"])
```